# Spring Batch unit test with Mockito

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application with one Job and several steps.

In the steps i call a tasklet. In the tasklet i query the database using jdbcTemplate and write the result to a text file.

What i would like to know is how can i write a unit test for my tasklet where i can mock the result of the findAll() function using mockito so that i don't need to populate the database as i am working with a view and it will be lengthy to create the appropriate tables and views.

I want to write test either for the tasklet or by launching the step also.

Below are my codes:

Step :

```
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Step myStep() throws IOException {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                .tasklet(new MyTasklet(filepath, encoding, jdbcTemplate))
                .build();
    }
```

Tasklet

```
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {

    private String filePath;

    private String encoding;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public MyTasklet (String filePath, String encoding, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.filePath= filePath;
        this.encoding = encoding;
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {


        Iterable<MyObject> objList= findAll();

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filePath+ "temp" + File.separator + "myFile.txt",encoding)) {

            for (MyObject myObj: objList) {

                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
                line.append("some data");
                ....
                line.append(myObj.getAttribute());

                writer.println(line);
            }
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    }

    public List<MyObject> findAll(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM V_MYVIEW";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new MyObjectRowMapper());

    }
```

I tried something like this but having

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<FINISHED> but was:<null>
```

```
   @Test
    public void testMyTaskletStep() throws Exception {

        MyObject myObj = new MyObject ();
        myObj.setXXX("columndata");
        ...

        List<MyObject> myobjList = new ArrayList<>();
        myobjList.add(myObj);

        StepExecution stepExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        StepContribution contrib = new StepContribution((stepExecution));
        ChunkContext context = new ChunkContext(new StepContext(stepExecution));

        MyTasklet myTasklet = Mockito.mock(MyTasklet.class);
        Mockito.when(myTasklet.findAll()).thenReturn(myobjList);
        RepeatStatus status = myTasklet.execute(contrib, context);
        Assert.assertEquals(RepeatStatus.FINISHED, status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the `JdbcTemplate` used by your `MyTasklet` and stub the value it returns when `query` is called.

In your test class you'll have:

```
...
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(),any())).thenReturn(myObjList);
MyTasklet myTasklet = new MyTasklet(filePath, encoding, jdbcTemplate);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the tasklet that you want to test which is wrong.

Quickest solution would be to new up the tasklet inside the test and override the findAll() method returning your List of MyObject

```
MyTasklet myTasklet = new MyTasklet(filePath, encoding, jdbcTemplate) {
    @Override
    public List<MyObject> findAll() {
        return myobjList;
    }
}
```

A working test would be something like the following although all you are testing is that the tasklet completes with RepeatStatus.FINISHED

```
@Test
public void testMyTasklet() throws Exception {

    String filePath = "/";
    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

    MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
    myObj.setXXX("columndata");

    List<MyObject> myobjList = new ArrayList<>();
    myobjList.add(myObj);

    MyTasklet myTasklet = new MyTasklet(filePath, encoding, jdbcTemplate) {
        @Override
        public List<MyObject> findAll() {
            return myobjList;
        }
    };

    RepeatStatus status = myTasklet.execute(null, null); // StepContribution & ChunkContext nul as not used
    assertEquals(RepeatStatus.FINISHED, status);
}
```

Comment: Really don't agree that overriding a method in the class under test is acceptable.

Comment: @tgdavies, wouldn't be my personal choice and had the findAll() method been private (which it should have been) that wouldn't be possible, but as it stands, it's an option